# Is it possible to make the peer join the channel as only committer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/scripts/script.sh has the command for joining a peer into a channel:
peer channel join -b $CHANNEL_NAME.block

This makes the peer join the channel as endorser and committer.

Is it possible to make the peer join the channel as only committer?

Thank you Yash for your question. Good to log for FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1) TLDR - don't install any chaincode on the peer
if you don't install the chaincode on the peer, it cannot be an endorser for that chaincode.  It will be aware of the chaincode via the instantiate transaction (which means it will have the endorsement policy - which is enforced at commit / validation time) and that will allow it to be a committer.

So if going through the getting started, you would skip this step:   https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#install-chaincode-onto-a-remote-peer

2) Channel policies support channel readers and writers so you could create an organization which only had read permission on the channel and therefore any peer from that organization would only be able to be a committer.  You can have a look at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configtx.html# to better understand channel config.

Option 1) is your best best for now to prove this out.  You can do these using Option 2 but the tooling around this is not quite there yet and there are a few change sets in play right now.

If the doc links I posted in-line above don't help shed light on this, please file a JIRA about the deficiency (using the component fabric-docs).

Thank you Gari for the response